# writing Array in class and objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I defined a Date class and Date objects. I want to write a compareTo method which compares the years of the dates of Date's. I want to compare d0 and d1, then d1 and d2, d2 and d3, d3 and d4.I want to crate an array list2 which has 1, 0 or -1.I got a problem when I call them from the Date class. I would be very happy to get any help.

```
public class HW_ObjectArrays 
{
    public static void main( String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println( "Start of HW_ObjectArrays\n");
        int i;
        Date d0, d1, d2, d3, d4;
        d0 = new Date(07,12,2014);
        d1 = new Date(23,06,2013);
        d2 = new Date(12,01,2012);
        d3 = new Date(12,01,2012);
        d4 = new Date(06,04,2011);
        Date[] list = new Date[5];
        list[0] = d0;
        list[1] = d1;
        list[2] = d2;
        list[3] = d3;
        list[4] = d4;

        int[] list2 = new int[4];
        System.out.println("d0 and d1 :" + compareTo(list2[0]));
        System.out.println("d1 and d2 :" + list2[1]);
        System.out.println("d2 and d3 :" + list2[2]);   
        System.out.println("d3 and d4 :" + list2[3]);    


public class Date
{
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }


    public int[] compareTo(Date d0, Date d1, Date d2, Date d3, Date d4)
    { 
        int i, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4;
        a0 = d0.getYear();
        a1 = d1.getYear();
        a2 = d2.getYear();
        a3 = d3.getYear();
        a4 = d4.getYear();
        int[] list = new int[5];
        list[0] = a0;   
        list[1] = a1;
        list[2] = a2;
        list[3] = a3;
        list[4] = a4;
        int[] list2 = new int[4];
        for (i = 0; i < list2.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
            {
                list2[i] = 1;
            }
            if (list[i] == list[i + 1])
            {
                list2[i] = 0;
            }
            if (list[i] < list[i + 1])
            {
            list2[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        return list2;

     }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us specifically what your problem is -- what behavior you see and what you expect, including any error messages/stack traces.

Comment: I want to compare the year of the dates. list2 should be [1,1,0,1] and I want to put them in place in System.out.println's.

Comment: You should be careful with the way you create your Date objects. You're using octal constants. In `new Date(06,04,2011)` the constants `06` and `04` are both base-8. If you ever try to create a date after July you're going to get some surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

Date class ;

```
public class Date
{
    private int day,month,year;
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
 public Date(int day,int month,int year){
     this.day =day;
     this.month= month;
     this.year=year;
 }

    public static int[] compareTo(Date[] date)
    { 
        int i, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4;
        a0 = date[0].getYear();
        a1 = date[1].getYear();
        a2 = date[2].getYear();
        a3 = date[3].getYear();
        a4 = date[4].getYear();
        int[] list = new int[5];
        list[0] = a0;   
        list[1] = a1;
        list[2] = a2;
        list[3] = a3;
        list[4] = a4;
        int[] list2 = new int[5];
        for (i = 0; i < list2.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
            {
                list2[i] = 1;
            }
            if (list[i] == list[i + 1])
            {
                list2[i] = 0;
            }
            if (list[i] < list[i + 1])
            {
            list2[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        return list2;

     }
}
```

HW_ObjectArrays class ;

```
public class HW_ObjectArrays 
{
    public static void main( String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println( "Start of HW_ObjectArrays\n");
        int i;
        Date d0, d1, d2, d3, d4;
        d0 = new Date(07,12,2014);
        d1 = new Date(23,06,2013);
        d2 = new Date(12,01,2012);
        d3 = new Date(12,01,2012);
        d4 = new Date(06,04,2011);
        Date[] list = new Date[5];
        list[0] = d0;
        list[1] = d1;
        list[2] = d2;
        list[3] = d3;
        list[4] = d4;

        int[] list2 =  Date.compareTo(list);
        System.out.println("d0 and d1 :" + list2[0]);
        System.out.println("d1 and d2 :" + list2[1]);
        System.out.println("d2 and d3 :" + list2[2]);   
        System.out.println("d3 and d4 :" + list2[3]);    

    }
}
```

Your code had lots of error, I try to make it ok, could you try please, is it ok?

Comment: It gives zero for all elements of list2.

Comment: I executed and the result is d0 and d1 :1
d1 and d2 :1
d2 and d3 :0
d3 and d4 :1

Comment: Please take al of the codes and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong. Now, it works. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change compare method to this:

```
public int compareTo(Date comparedObject){

    if(comparedObjct.getYear() > this.getYear()){
        return -1;
    } else if(comparedObjct.getYear() > this.getYear()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

And yout main should look like this, where results is your results array

```
public static void main(){

    Date[] list1 = ... /* Create the list  */    
    Date[] list2 = ... /* Create the list  */    
    int[] results = new int[list1.legth];

    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
        results[i] = list1[i].compareTo(list2[i]);
    }
}
```